# android viewswitcher with multiple views

Tags: android, viewswitcher

I have a specific question in android development as I am a relative noob.

Currently I am trying to setup a slideshow of various images, and this is the class I am trying to get to work, but eclipse tells me an error that

"multiple markers at this line. viewswitcher cannot be resolved to a type"

class MyAdapter extends Adapter
  implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory

I cannot figure this out, and was wondering what the problem mean-what do you think is the error for?

Comment: Have you added `import android.widget.ViewSwitcher` to the beginning of your code? Are your sure `ViewSwitcher` is written like that, caps and all, and not in lowercase? Please make sure you write both the code and the error exactly like in Eclipse / the debugger...

Comment: Google is your friend. There's an example here: http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-a-viewswitcher-in-your-android-xml-layouts/

Comment: @Christine-I had a look at the link, but it only shows for two views, not multiple images...

Comment: You may want to look at this [example using ImageSwitcher](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f77b0da0a00e9c5809f93/android.widget.ImageSwitcher?tag=antelope)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, `ViewSwitcher` can only have 2 children.

Sounds like you need `ImageSwitcher.`